# Proper formatting for if statements inside loops

Tags: syntax, coding-style

I'm curious which of the following is considered better form. My examples are snippets, but in more complex programs I've written, I can see arguments for and have used either.

**Option 1: Skip ahead if a condition is met, otherwise execute lots of code:**

```
for i in range(5):
    if i == 3:
        continue
    print i
    # and do lots of other stuff
```

The argument for this: clearly skips certain condition, doesn't result in overly nested code.

**Option 2: Execute lots of code if condition is not met:**

```
for i in range(5):
    if i is not 3:
        print i
        # and do lots of other stuff
```

The argument for this: more verbose and doesn't use unnecessary `continue`.

(There seems to be a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226416/for-loop-syntax-with-if-statements-inside) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846605/long-code-blocks-inside-if-statements-or-for-loops) related to this, but mostly about using functions or long blocks of code. I'm curious about the `==` vs `!=` part.)

Answer (score 1):

I think that, generally, Option 1 is better practice. In Option 2, 'lots of other stuff' is at a second level on indentation. Generally, the less indentation, the better.